React Native Npm Install Error ERESOLVE could not resolve
React Native
I am trying to upgrade the node version of my react-native project
from node 14.20.0 to node >=18
I upgraded my local node version to 20.12.0 using nvm and set it to default
there's a .npmrc file which have 14.20.0 text only which i updated to my local node version 20.12.0
While installing the npm packages with command npm install I am getting following error
It seems the dependencies are not matching and having compatibility issues
npm error
npm errorcode ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: better-docs@2.7.2
npm error Found: react@18.2.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error
npm error react@"^18.2.0" from the root project peer react@"*" from @jsamr/react-native-li@2.3.1
npm error node_modules/@jsamr/react-native-li
npm error @i samr/react-native-li@"^2.3.0" from react-native-render-html@6.3.4
npm error node modules/react-native-render-html
npm error react-native-render-html@"^6.3.4" from the root project
npm error 43 more (@react-native-community/art, ...)
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^17.0.2" from better-docs@2.7.2
npm error node_modules/better-docs
npm error dev better-docs@"^2.7.2" from the root project
npm error
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm error node_modules/react
peer react@"^17.0.2" from better-docs@2.7.2
npm error
node modules/better-docs
npm error
dev better-docs@"^2.7.2" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with -force or -legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) `dependency resolution.`
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error /Users/A
/- npm/_1ogs/2024-08-1603_14_07_339Z-eresolve-report.txt

full error image link
Things that i have already tried

npm packages still installs as expected which i switch back to node 14.20.0

npm install --legacy-peer-deps (works but fails again when npm installed command is executed)

adding node engine to package.json
"engines": {
"node": ">=18"
}


Things that I want to achieve

upgrade to react-native project node version


you have to remove the better-docs because it support until react 17.0.2
